# For $a\geq2$, $b\geq2$ and $c\geq2$, prove that $\left(a^3+b\right)\left(b^3+c\right)\left(c^3+a\right)\geq125 abc$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

> For $a\geq2$, $b\geq2$ and $c\geq2$, prove that
>
> $$(a^3+b)(b^3+c)(c^3+a)\geq 125 abc.$$

My try:

First I wrote the inequality as

$$\left(a^2+\frac{b}{a}\right) \left(b^2+\frac{c}{b}\right) \left(c^2+\frac{a}{c}\right) \geq 125. $$

Then I noted that

$$a^2+\frac{b}{a}\geq a^2+\frac{2}{a}, \\ b^2+\frac{c}{b}\geq b^2+\frac{2}{b}, \\  c^2+\frac{a}{c}\geq c^2+\frac{2}{c}. $$

But I don't know how this can help me.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, including the source of the problem and any motivation or relation to other problems in mathematics.

Comment: @CarlMummert Maybe your comment was before it was edited, but it looks fine to me.

Comment: @Jakobian: no source or motivation is given for the problem in the current version. The "try" is not particularly enlightening, it's just a trivial rewriting of the problem, and doesn't really add any information about the problem.

Comment: I disagree. He clearly tries to write the inequality as $f(a)f(b)f(c)\geq 125$ where $f(x)=x^2+\frac{2}{x}$. I'm not sure how many information can you give about one problem. It's probably an exercise from the book. This seems ridiculous to me

Comment: @Jakobian: if it is an exercise from a book, it would be easy enough to say which book!

Comment: @CarlMummert This problem is an exercise from my Brazilian book. Are you interested on it?

Comment: @Duarte: in this site, we are interested in posts which do more than just include a problem to solve.  Yes, you should say which book you took the problem from! There is additional advice at [Provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), including what to do when you don't know how to start a problem.  In general, this site is not intended merely as a place to copy problems from elsewhere without motivation - it is intended for a place to ask *questions* about problems.

Comment: Ho. Sorry for that then. I'm new here. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: It seem @CarlMummert downvote all of my answers. Why that, please? Sorry if a made mistake.

Comment: @Dinesh Shankar: looking at your reputation list [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/406091/dinesh-shankar?tab=reputation), only three of your answers have been downvoted today, so *nobody* has downvoted all of your answers.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: You're right! Sorry for that. I think I will not answer questions from new users anymore

Comment: I think we need to open this topic. In my opinion it's not off-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$a^3+b = {a^3\over 4}+{a^3\over 4}+{a^3\over 4}+{a^3\over 4}+b\geq 5\sqrt[5]{a^{12}b\over 2^8}$$

$$b^3+c = {b^3\over 4}+{b^3\over 4}+{b^3\over 4}+{b^3\over 4}+c\geq 5\sqrt[5]{b^{12}c\over 2^8}$$

$$c^3+a = {c^3\over 4}+{c^3\over 4}+{c^3\over 4}+{c^3\over 4}+a\geq 5\sqrt[5]{c^{12}a\over 2^8}$$

So $$\left(a^3+b\right)\left(b^3+c\right)\left(c^3+a\right) \geq 125abc\sqrt[5]{a^8b^8c^8\over 2^{24}}\geq 125abc$$

Comment: By generalized Hölder we have $$\left(a^2+\frac{b}{a}\right) \left(b^2+\frac{c}{b}\right) \left(c^2+\frac{a}{c}\right)\geq\left(\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}+\sqrt[3]{1}\right)^3\geq(\sqrt[3]{4\cdot4\cdot4}+1)^3=5^3=125.$$

Answer (score 5):

You did 90% of the work. You can finish it by using a little bit of Calculus.

Let

$$f(x)=x^2+\frac{2}{x}.$$

Since the derivate of $f(x)$ is positive, the function $f(x)$ is increasing for $x\geq2$, and then

$$f(x)\geq f(2)=5.$$

Thereby,

$$a^2+\frac{b}{a}\geq 5, \\ b^2+\frac{c}{b}\geq 5,\\ c^2+\frac{a}{c}\geq 5,$$

which implies that

$$ \left(a^2+\frac{b}{a}\right) \left(b^2+\frac{c}{b}\right) \left(c^2+\frac{a}{c}\right) \geq 125.$$

Comment: It is not necessary to use calculus to prove monotonicity of $f$ on $[2,\infty)$, though, but good solution nonetheless.

Comment: This is easiest, I'd say. You can even just do this before the division with $ a^3 + b \geq 10 $, directly using the inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

By AM-GM for all $x\geq2$ we obtain:
$$x^3+16=x^3+8+8\geq3\sqrt[3]{x^3\cdot8^2}=12x.$$
Thus, $$\prod_{cyc}(a^3+b)\geq\prod_{cyc}(12a-16+b)=\prod_{cyc}(5a+7a+b-16)\geq\prod_{cyc}5a=125abc.$$